# Sending input form values to PHP with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

After several tries I'm still having serious problems making Ajax Post Method working.

```
<form id="search_box" method="POST" action="" >
<input class="SEARCH" type="text" name="search_name" id="search_name" placeholder="Search product by name" /></form>

$(document).ready(function(e) {
$( "#search_box" ).submit(function() {
var search_name = $("#search_name").val();  
$.ajax({  
      type: "GET",
      url: "shop/pages/fetch_name.php",  
      data: "search_name=" + search_name,
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(risposta) {  
        $("#results").html(risposta);  
      },
      error: function(){
        alert("No results.");
      } 
}); 
e.preventDefault();

if(isset($_POST["search_name"])){$item_name_fetch = $_POST['search_name'];}
```

Looking for some help..

Comment: thanks anyway for your answer. I'm trying to create a function for searching products stored in a mysql table typing the name. Starting all from a php page that create a result using jquery to paginate the response of the search..

Comment: `dataType: "post-form='+postcontent"` is nonsense. See [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). `(xml, json, script, or html)`

Comment: In my personal case, the problem was not the ajax code that is correct. Just fixed the problem relative to the entire function substituting e.preventDefault(); with return false;

Answer (score 1):

This is a little bit strange

Because you don't use answer of request in your ajax call....
You need define 'success and error'.

Another thing is strange to me is your dataType, you should choose one of then:
xml, json, script, or html

And you should use preventDefault()
https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/preventDefault

Example of  one of Ajax with asw in json:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="search_name" id="search_name" />
    <button id="btn-send">Send</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {


        $(document).ready(function() {
            $( "#btn-send" ).bind( "click", function() {
                $.ajax({
                     url: 'myjson.php'
                    ,data: $('#search_name').serialize()
                    ,type:'POST'
                    ,dataType: 'json'
                    ,success: function(json){
                        console.log(json);
                    }
                    ,error: function(json){
                        console.log(json);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Check this oficial page:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

myjson.php

```
<?php

print json_encode($_POST['search_name']);
```

Comment: thanks Gabriel, trying if(!isset($_POST["search_name"])) & if(isset($_POST["search_name"])) results that $_POST is not detected. Your solution does not work and give me null as response

Comment: I don't post any solution...

Just example for "Sending input form values to PHP with AJAX"
And some notes about your code

I have sure you make some mistake beacause i tried my example before post here...